# how to read a text file column by column and find the minimum value in every column

Tags: python

I have a file called `store_x_axis.txt` which contains of

```
0.02153753289089977,0.01666949746870028,0.012109153483800483
0.01812035460886907,0.013230902143324563,0.008647475872060717
0.014703176326838374,0.009792306817948848,0.005185798260320951
0.011285998044807677,0.006353711492574021,0.0020684929408965047
0.00786881976277698,0.002915116167198306,0.0017375569631585819
0.004451641480746282,0.0007780382940847375,0.005199234574898348
0.001100981972369297,0.003962074483552236,0.008660912186638114
0.0023827150833160005,0.007400669808927951,0.01212258979837788
0.00579989336534581,0.010839265134302778,0.015584267410117647
```

and I wish to get my minimum value through every column: `0.001100981972369297,0.007400669808927951` and `0.008647475872060717`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Format your question carefully please. / What have you tried and where are you stuck at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, common tasks are often automated / optimised via libraries. The below code uses the `numpy` library to process your task:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', delimiter=',')

arr_colmin = arr.min(axis=0)
```